# Symfony2 MoneyType with divisor: integer conversion leads to wrong database values

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

We're storing all our money related values as cents in our database (ODM but ORM will likely behave the same). We're using MoneyType to convert user facing values (12,34€) into their cents representation (1234c). The [typical float precision](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/) problem arises here: due to insufficient precision there are many cases that create rounding errors that are merely visible when debugging. MoneyType will convert incoming strings to **floats** that may be not precise ("1765" => 1764.9999999998).

Things get bad as soon as you persist these values:

```
class Price {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
     **/
    protected $cents;
}
```

will transform the incoming values (which are *float*!) like:

```
namespace Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Types;
class IntType extends Type
{
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value)
    {
        return $value !== null ? (integer) $value : null;
    }
}
```

The (integer) cast will strip off the value's mantissa instead of rounding the value, effectively leading to writing wrong values into the database (1764 instead of 1765 when "1765" is internally 1764.9999999998).

Here's an unit test that should display the issue from within any Symfony2 container:

```
//for better debugging: set ini_set('precision', 17); 

class PrecisionTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private function buildForm() {
        $builder = $this->getContainer()->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, null, []);
        $form = $builder->add('money', MoneyType::class, [
            'divisor' => 100
        ])->getForm();
        return $form;
    }

    // high-level symptom
    public function testMoneyType() {
        $form = $this->buildForm();
        $form->submit(['money' => '12,34']);

        $data = $form->getData();

        $this->assertEquals(1234, $data['money']);
        $this->assertEquals(1234, (int)$data['money']);

        $form = $this->buildForm();
        $form->submit(['money' => '17,65']);

        $data = $form->getData();

        $this->assertEquals(1765, $data['money']);
        $this->assertEquals(1765, (int)$data['money']); //fails: data[money] === 1764 
    }

    //root cause
    public function testParsedIntegerPrecision() {

        $string = "17,65";
        $transformer = new MoneyToLocalizedStringTransformer(2, false,null, 100);
        $value = $transformer->reverseTransform($string);

        $int = (integer) $value;
        $float = (float) $value;

        $this->assertEquals(1765, (float)$float);
        $this->assertEquals(1765, $int); //fails: $int === 1764
    }
```

}

Note, that this issue is not always visible! As you can see "12,34" is working well, "17,65" or "18,65" will fail.

What is the best way to work around here (in terms of Symfony Forms / Doctrine)? The NumberTransformer or MoneyType aren't supposed to return integer values - people might also want to save floats so we cannot solve the issue there. I thought about overriding the IntType in the persistence layer, effectively *rounding* every incoming integer value instead of casting. Another approach would be to store the field as float in MongoDB...

The basic PHP problem [is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193593/php-money-string-conversion-to-integer-error).

Comment: Try to use `DecimalType` to store float values as `NUMERIC(precision, scale)`, this one comeback as string without affect the original precision.

Comment: yeah, I thought so. But I find it so weird to store obviously "float" values (1765.00) as "int".

Comment: I want to say without 100 divisor ("17.65")

Comment: @Yonel: https://www.google.com/search?q=dont%20store%20currency%20as%20float%20in%20database top hits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224462/storing-money-in-a-decimal-column-what-precision-and-scale (2nd answer), https://www.noelherrick.com/blog/always-use-decimal-for-money , https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mysql-why-not-double-or-float-for-storing-money/195731/7

Comment: `DecimalType` doesn't store values as float, but string, so there isn't DB float precision issues. Just use a right precision/scale to avoid data truncation. Unless you need to perform PHP math operation with this number, you don't need care about this by using Decimal DBAL type, IMHO.

Comment: Decimal has been introduced to mongo only very recently (3.4). As soon as doctrine odm catches up with this, I'd be fine I guess. Nevertheless I think that this is an issue that should be addressed by a framework component. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541939/mongodb-what-about-decimal-type-of-value

Answer (score 3):

For now I decided to go with my own MoneyType that calls "round" on integers internally.

```
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class MoneyToLocalizedStringTransformer extends \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\MoneyToLocalizedStringTransformer {

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        return round(parent::reverseTransform($value));
    }
}

class MoneyType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->addViewTransformer(new MoneyToLocalizedStringTransformer(
                $options['scale'],
                $options['grouping'],
                null,
                $options['divisor']
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this problem is more related to persistence layer and I would try to solve it by overriding `ODM`'s `int` type:

`AppBundle\Doctrine\Types\MyIntType`:

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Types\IntType;

class MyIntType extends IntType
{
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value)
    {
        return $value !== null ? round($value) : null;
    }
}
```

`app/config/config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            int:  AppBundle\Doctrine\Types\MyIntType
```

Comment: I don't quite agree as this fixes the outcome of problem, not the cause. The entity says it's storing price in cents yet it ends with 12.97 whcih is not reflecting possible real life state as one can't have 0.97c. In my opinion the problem should be fixed in Symfony's transformer as @Stefan suggested in his answer

Comment: @Andrey Mischenko: That was exactly my first approach (only in ODM) but then I thought about malarzm's argument. Your suggestion would indeed solve the problem, though. However, I don't like the idea that *every* incoming integer has to pass "round".